Missing concrete implementation of 'State.Widget' in Flutter even though it was not there before
I am not sure why the issue is coming to the code, I have tried multiple fixes but nothing is working and the similar kind of issue is with other parts of the project too. I am not sure how to fix it, it already has Build Context in Widget still I am not sure what it is lacking.
Missing concrete implementation of 'State.Widget'.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.dartnon_abstract_class_inherits_abstract_member
class _MonthDateRowState extends State<MonthDateRow>
package:study_sync/Pages/home.dart

Here's the code:
class MonthDateRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MonthDateRow> createState() => _MonthDateRowState();
}

class _MonthDateRowState extends State<MonthDateRow> {
  late ApiService _apiService;
  late TokenStorageService _tokenStorageService;
  List<VideoModel>? _videos;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  String? _errorMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tokenStorageService = TokenStorageService();
    _apiService = ApiService(
      'https://fe00-117-220-236-245.ngrok-free.app/api',
      _tokenStorageService,
    );
    _fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);
    try {
      final token = await _tokenStorageService.getToken() ?? '';
      final fetchedVideos = await _apiService.fetchVideos(token);
      setState(() {
        _videos = fetchedVideos.cast<VideoModel>();
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        _errorMessage = error.toString();
      });
    }
  }

  List<DateTime> _getNextDates(int count) {
    return List.generate(
      count,
      (index) => DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index)),
    );
  }

  
  Widget Build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return _loadingWidget();
    } else if (_errorMessage != null) {
      return _errorWidget();
    } else if (_videos == null || _videos!.isEmpty) {
      return _emptyWidget();
    } else {
      return _videosWidget();
    }
  }

  Widget _loadingWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Scheduled Videos')),
      body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }

  Widget _errorWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Error')),
      body: Center(child: Text(_errorMessage!)),
    );
  }

  Widget _emptyWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Scheduled Videos')),
      body: Center(child: Text('No scheduled videos found')),
    );
  }

  Widget _videosWidget() {
    final dateList = _getNextDates(20);
    int videoIndex = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Scheduled Videos')),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dateList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final date = dateList[index];
          final video = _videos![videoIndex % _videos!.length];
          videoIndex++;

          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d').format(date),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              _buildScheduledVideo(context, video),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildScheduledVideo(BuildContext context, VideoModel video) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.video_library),
        title: Text(
          video.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(video.videoUrl),
        trailing: Text(DateFormat.jm().format(video.scheduledDate)),
      ),
    );
  }
}


How can I fix this?

You are missing the implementation of the abstract build method
That's what you have done, but it's not the build method.
  Widget Build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return _loadingWidget();
    } else if (_errorMessage != null) {
      return _errorWidget();
    } else if (_videos == null || _videos!.isEmpty) {
      return _emptyWidget();
    } else {
      return _videosWidget();
    }
  }

Fix
Modify the method signature like this
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {}

Hope it helps you.

Yes yes! I edited this still the issue of the class _MonthDateRowState is still there. Please suggest a fix and similar kind of issue is on other files as well.

build is method name not class name always use. you need to change method name also use @override:
from this:
Widget Build(BuildContext context) {}
to this:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {}


Yes yes! even though I edited this still the issue of the class _MonthDateRowState  is still there. Please suggest a fix and similar kind of issue is on other files as well.

use this code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MonthDateRow extends StatefulWidget {
  const MonthDateRow({super.key});

  @override
  State<MonthDateRow> createState() => _MonthDateRowState();
}

class _MonthDateRowState extends State<MonthDateRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
